# Formatting doubles with highest possible precision

Tags: java, floating-point, double, precision

A number such as 0.1 cannot be precisely represented using binary floating point, so I want to print it out with the highest possible precision. I know that the 64-bit `double` type only gives meaningful precision up to about 15 digits, but further digits would reveal the difference between the floating-point approximation and the real value.

However, a format with high precision specification such as `"%.50f"` still doesn't give me it:

```
String.format("%.50f", 0.1)    --> "0.10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
new BigDecimal(0.1).toString() --> "0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625"
```

Is there any way to output the number as a string without using `BigDecimal`?

Comment: Sure. Just `toString()` the original `double`.

Comment: @Jorn that just gives "0.1"

Comment: Which is exactly all the precision that is available. So I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: Something that gives "0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625" without using BigDecimal

Comment: That's not possible. You'll have to use BigDecimal. Also, why would you even want that? The long number is in no way a better representation of the `0.1` literal in the input.

Comment: For example, one possible use is to prove that a certain number can't be precisely represented, while another number certainly can. For example, 0.125 can be precisely represented, and `new BigDecimal(0.125).toString()` gives "0.125" meaning that the floating-point representation of 0.125 is not just an approximation but is exactly and precisely equal to the real number 0.125.

Comment: Isn't that just a result of converting to BigDecimal? If the `double` variant prints `0.1`, it's represented as 0.1. If it wasn't, it would print something like `0.09999999999999`.

Comment: I'm no Java expert, but I don't see why this would not be a valid question. E.g., in C/C++ `printf("%.100g", 0.1)` prints out `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` (what OP expects) -- of course YMMV, since a lot in C and C++ is compiler/target specific. Having an output of `"0.10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"` looks very wrong (is Java just appending `0`s at the end?)

Comment: `BigDecimal` is giving the correct stored value (0xCCCCCCCCCCCCD * 2^-55) here.  Is there a reason you don't want to use it?  Because AFAICT, any solution would basically amount to reinventing `BigDecimal`'s formatting routine.

Comment: @dan04 using `BigDecimal` is a satisfactory solution, but it feels a bit wrong: firstly, formatting is not the main purpose of `BigDecimal`; and secondly, `String.format` (and `System.out.printf` etc) ought to do the "right thing" just like the C version of printf, or the Linux/GNU command line printf.

Comment: This seems to be the difference between compile and run-time evaluation. The compiler sees 0.1 as string "0.1" without a declared type, so it is free to evaluate the first expression with a multi-precision type like BigDecimal with enough digits to avoid rounding errors in the result. One would have to check what the actual compiled instructions are, or if there are compiler flags to switch off such early evaluation.

Comment: @LutzLehmann it's not the compiler being clever, you still get the same output if you do `System.out.printf("%.30f", new Scanner(System.in).nextDouble());` and enter 0.1 at the console, so that the compiler doesn't know what the value will be, so it's all definitely done at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the last meaningful digit might be either rounded up or down, one cannot just glue 00...00 (99...99) after it.

So as there still is an approximation error after some 15 odd digits, `new BigDecimal("...")` is the appropriate solution. You could assume that the actual precision is 14 or lower and then add zeroes. But still `printf/format` gives fake news.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add another answer with more detail:

The ["%f" format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#dndec) is specifically documented to add 0s after the decimal point:

> ... zeros may be appended to reach the precision. For a canonical
> representation of the value, use Float.toString(float) or
> Double.toString(double) as appropriate.

And [Double.toString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)) is documented to return an approximation using the following logic:

> How many digits must be printed for the fractional part of m or a?
> There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and
> beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to
> uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type
> double.

So, to get a String representation of *exactly* what the binary floating-point value represents, it seems Java offers BigDecimal as the only option.